# Does large number of commented code affect the size of class file?

Tags: java, class, comments

I have a code that I commnented out as it was no longer needed.

It was some 1000 lines.

So just wanted to know whether keeping that code inside my java file affect the size of the compiled class file?

I saw my class file size but I am not sure whether it was reduced or not.

Comment: Why don't you compile two java source files to classes; one with lot of comments, other without and compare compiled .class files?

Comment: You can also look a compiled class with a java decompiler to see if the comments are there or not.

Comment: Unless you really need to hang on to it due to uncertainty over your solution, you really should avoid leaving commented out code in your classes, especially if other people will see/use your code too. If you no longer need it, get rid of it. Many a time have I been thrown by a confusing commented out line of code without explanation...

Comment: @Averroes what do you mean by decompiler ?

Comment: An application that takes a .class file and show you its contents in a readable way. Like this one: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the comments are removed before the class file is created. I don't know about java but in C language this work is done by the pre processor. The preprocessor is responsible for replacing the macros with their replacement and removing the comments.

Comment: The question is about Java, not C, but the main part of the answer is correct.

Comment: I am just sharing my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. But keeping such a large number of commented lines is not a best practice. Don't you have revision system? It is better than keeping large number of commented code which you are not using.

Answer (score 1):

javac compiler will throw away all comments. So the file size should be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The commented code is no longer part of the Java code so when compiled  class file is generated it doesn't have any commented code in it.

Answer (score 0):

> So just wanted to know whether keeping that code inside my java file affect the size of the compiled class file?

No, Commented code is not part of class file.

But, if you are using version-control system, you should remove the comments also to enhance readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not include this in java... Just to verify at your own, you can create a class file and use any decompiler to check the .class file...

In my case I have created following file

```
/**
 * This file is just to check whether this comment is part of class file.
 * @author ICEME048
 *
 */

public class A {

    public void changeB(B b){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }


 }
```

And it .class file's content are as following

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class A
{
  public void changeB(B b)
  {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  }
}
```

I have decompiler to check the content of the class file.